# Data integrity problem C#

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, overwrite

my problem is that the assignment of decodedProxyExcerpt2 below overwrites decodedProxyExcerpt1 and I do not know why.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

```
        DecodedProxyExcerpt decodedProxyExcerpt1 = new DecodedProxyExcerpt(stepSize);
        if (audiofactory.MoveNext(stepSize))
        {
            decodedProxyExcerpt1 = audiofactory.Current(stepSize);
        }
        // At this point decodedProxyExcerpt1.data contains the correct values.

        DecodedProxyExcerpt decodedProxyExcerpt2 = new DecodedProxyExcerpt(stepSize);
        if (audiofactory.MoveNext(stepSize))
        {
            decodedProxyExcerpt2 = audiofactory.Current(stepSize);
        }
        // At this point decodedProxyExcerpt2.data contains the correct values.
        // However, decodedProxyExcerpt1.data is overwritten and now holds the values of decodedProxyExcerpt2.data.


public class DecodedProxyExcerpt
{
    public short[] data { get; set; } // PCM data

    public DecodedProxyExcerpt(int size)
    {
        this.data = new short[size];
    }

}
```

From AudioFactory:

```
    public bool MoveNext(int stepSize)
    {
        if (index == -1)
        {
            index = 0;
            return (true);
        }
        else
        {
            index = index + stepSize;
            if (index >= buffer.Length - stepSize)
                return (false);
            else
                return (true);
        }
    }

    public DecodedProxyExcerpt Current(int stepSize)
    {
        Array.Copy(buffer, index, CurrentExcerpt.data, 0, stepSize);
        return(CurrentExcerpt);
    }}
```

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to know what is happening - your problem could well be inside audioFactory.

Comment: Post the code of audiofactory.Current(stepSize), obviously the error lies there;

Comment: +1 on where the bug is. It's pretty hard to imagine a data integrity problem in C# or .NET after seven years. Deep inside the CLR or in multiprocessing code, maybe, but not in simple, single-threaded code.

Comment: How does CurrentExcerpt get set in the AudioFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of classes are stored as references.

decodedProxyExcerpt1 and decodedProxyExcerpt2 are both references to the same object -- audiofactory.CurrentExcerpt.

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of it `audiofactory.MoveNext(stepSize)` is staying at the same reference. This is causing `audiofactory.Current(stepSize)` to stay at the same address.

For this reason, but `decodedProxyExcerpt1` and `decodedProxyExcerpt2` point to the same reference and therefore changes to one propagate to the other.

So, the problems lies in your `AudioFactory` class.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a friend about this who gave me the hint that I might have been thinking in C++ where assignment of an array creates a copy, instead of C# where assignment of an array creates a reference.

If that is correct and

decodedProxyExcerpt1 = audiofactory.Current(stepSize);

is setting a reference (not a copy) then the overwrite is completely understandable.